# Adding a composer package to Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, package, composer-php, packagist

```
"require": {
    "infusionsoft/php-sdk": "^1.2",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.2",
    "goaop/framework": "^2.0",
    "php-http/httplug": "^1.1",
    "infusionsoft/old-php-isdk": "*"
},
```

I'm trying to use the "infusionsoft/old-php-isdk" which is in the packagist composer repository but it's not specific to Laravel. I'm using an order controller and it's code that I picked up from another developer so he references the current (and working) "infusionsoft/php-sdk" as the following

"use infusionsoft\infusionsoft;"

What namespace do I call it if it has no namespace from the package?

Here's the original link to the composer package.
https://packagist.org/packages/infusionsoft/old-php-isdk

Am I missing something? Do I need to assign it a namespace? What and where would I put it?

Comment: After you download the package via composer, does a simple ```new iSDK();``` call (from their documentation) not work?

Comment: Correct, it says missing class in /app/Http/Controller/iSDK (but that's not a real directory, that's only the directory of my Controller @georaldc

Comment: Does it just not get placed in the root namespace?    `new \iSDK();`

Comment: @joe I've tried that as well, when looking into the old-php-isdk there is no namespace defined. when I do define it as 

"namespace infusionsoftold;"

Then call it in my controller using

use Infusionsoftold;
use Infusionsoftold\iSDK;

It then gives me errors for missing every other class that it calls which is then into another separate directory for the xmlrpc-3.0.0 file.